# Vaseline or Teflon grease near potable water?

Tags: safety, health, storage, drinking-water, rv

I want to install a deck plate in the top of the fresh water tank of my camp trailer (RV) to allow for cleaning the inside at the start of the season.  The [product I am looking at](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00863N3Z2) recommends "Lubricate with Vaseline or Teflon grease".

Looking around to see if Teflon is toxic I found this [Non-toxic when used in quantities and applications as intended; contains no carcinogenic or hazardous air polluting (HAP) ingredients, and emits no Volatile Organic Compounds (VOCs)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002L5UL92) but here it is being sold as bicycle lubricant.

When choosing between Vaseline or Teflon to lubricate and seal a potable fresh water tank, which is the better choice?

P.S. Thanks to "RV Geezer" who suggested this in a review I found while looking for a deck plate to use for my boat.

Comment: I've used vaseline on chapped lips, I wouldn't use bike lube...so I'd just use Vaseline to be safe, if it was me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Teflon is a brand name. The scientific name is [Polytetrafluoroethylene (PTFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene).

Searching more I find there are [food grade PTFE lubricants available. (*Super Lube*)](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/lube.html)

Points making PTFE appropriate for this application

- Great for installing some faucet stems and cartridges
- Food grade. U.S.D.A. rated H-1
- Non-toxic, biodegradable
- Odorless, clean, non-staining

I found several references to using Vaseline in plumbing applications.

[Vaseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaseline) is brand name for [Petroleum jelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_jelly) it has been used and is FDA approved for health and skin use.

Currently I think;

In a high volume water system like home plumbing, either is fine. With Vaseline being less expensive it maybe preferred.  Probably comes down to personal choice.

In a low volume water system like a self contained RV water storage system. Either should be safe, but the Teflon seems to have a slight edge, making the higher cost worth while.

Comment: Of course PTFE is commonly used in contact with food (non stick pans) but it's not meant to come off and be consumed.

Comment: @ChrisH the points above are specific to the application as used in the lubricant

Comment: Do you use a high volume of Vaseline for your home plumbing?   In 20 years I have not used up 2 oz of plumbers grease.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent self-answered question. It's a great way to teach us something using your own research, and is [always encouraged](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) around the SE  network.

Comment: @Sue thanks, I did not know the answer, when I posted the question. I could not let it go, until I tracked down the answer over the next hour or so.

Comment: You're just like me! Once I'm into something I can't let it go either.  It's still a great answer!